# Two different voltage input to be monitored by microcontroller

Tags: comparator

I just wanted to make a detailed circuit design that I can use in my project.
a design that can supplement on the OR gate

Given the two different voltage input, I need an output of a voltage around microcontroller readable values with protection circuit on it.Maybe I need level shifting and protection?
Please help.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Same ground? Have you looked up voltage shift logic circuits?

Comment: At what nominal voltage on the 0-16v input do you want it to flip between true and false?

Comment: Hi user44635,  I actually wanted to switch the two inputs between true or false (Ignition is between OFF: 4V or less and ON: 6V or more) and (Micon is between ON:5V～2.5 OFF:0～0.8V like that)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a resistive divider to your ignition input, to make the output around 4-5V. 
For the output of your OR gate, add a resistive divider as well.

A very simple OR port can also be made using two diodes, as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGznbt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that R1 and R3 form a resistive divider, to make the 5V into less than 2V. The 3 resistors form a divider for the 16V, making it less than 2V as well.